# handle click on iconmenu item

Tags: android, menu

I see that it's possible to handle a tap on a icon menù item or by implementing

```
onOptionsItemSelected
```

inside the acivity, or by using

```
onMenuItemClickListener
```

like onclick listener on a button. When is better to use the fist one method, and when the second one?
Because for my opinion, using an external listener makes more modular the code, but create a new class, but using the first way don't create new class, but makes code less modular...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are use cases other than the ones outlined below, but I'm putting in the general cases that come up regularly.

**onOptionsItemSelected**

If you're using `Fragment`s, you may want to use `onOptionsItemSelected` and consider adding menu items to the *Action Bar* the way that is described in [Adding items to the Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#ActionBar).

What this describes is implementing [onCreateOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu,%20android.view.MenuInflater%29) inside your `Fragment`. To make this happen, you must call [setHasOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu%28boolean%29) in `onCreate`.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Setting this will actually make the `Activity` call `onCreateOptionsMenu` which allows you to add the menu items.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    // add items corresponding to this Fragment
    menu.add(...);

    return true;
}
```

The reason I recommend this is that it allows you to put more of the menu handling code into your `Fragment` instead of the `Activity` to figure out which `Fragment` to call, etc.

In this case, clicking the menu item will call `onOptionsItemSelected` inside of your `Fragment` which I suggest.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.my_id1:
            dothing1();
            return true;
        case R.id.my_id2:
            dotghing2();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

More of a long winded answer, but this is the way to handle menu clicks inside your `Fragment`.

**onMenuItemClickListener**

In the case of `onMenuItemClickListener`, this is used when you DON'T want to use the pre-ready method above and implement your own.

What I mean by that is you *implement* `OnMenuItemClickListener` and generate the methods in the interface. You then assign the menu to call the `Activity` that implemented this where as the above option assumes what `Activity` to use based on the pre-ready implementation of the `Activity` to `Fragment` relationship.

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting API 14 or greater (ICS or above) you could implement an [ActionProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionProvider.html). If that's not an option then you could implement a base activity that will always populate the menu and handle any menu clicks using `onOptionsItemSelected`. This is a good approach to implement "About" or "Settings" menu items through all your activities.